# How to customize a plugin whilst maintaining ability to upgrade

Tags: plugins, upgrade

I am currently working on a major update to one of my WordPress plugins.

The plugin lets the user choose from several available skins. Quite often I get asked to create a custom skin. To prevent this skin from being deleted on upgrade I have to use a WordPress hook to disable automatic updates for the plugin. This is obviously not ideal as I would want them to still be able to update the plugin. The problem is the way WordPress handles updates - it simply deletes the plugin folder and installs the new version. Thus removing files which were not actually part of the old version.

Currently the only way I can get around it is having two skins folders - one in the plugin folder and one in the uploads folder - is this really the only way I can offer this to my users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many plugins use `/wp-content/custom-plugin-folder/` to store customized plugin data (WPTouch comes to mind).

Just use the constants `WP_CONTENT_URL` and `WP_CONTENT_DIR` <sup>[Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants)</sup> to check for the existence of your folder and retrieve any available skins.

The following article, although not directly related to this Question, explains the importance for plugins/themes to search for translations **first** in the `wp-content/languages` folder **before** loading its own packaged `.mo` files. It's a worth read and hopefully you'll apply the concept in your next release :)

> [Loading WordPress language files the right way](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way)
>   <sup>`http://www.geertdedeckere.be/`</sup>
>   **I would like to point out that is important to load custom user language files from WP_LANG_DIR before you load the language files
>   that ship with the plugin**. When multiple mo-files are loaded for the
>   same domain, the first found translation will be used. This way the
>   language files provided by the plugin will serve as a fallback for
>   strings not translated by the user.

Answer (score 7):

The other way is to have people add their own sub-plugin.  For example, the code in your core plugin that gets the skins could be something like:

```
function get_available_skins() {
    $skins[] = '/includes/default-skin.css';
    $skins[] = '/includes/2012-skin.css';

    return apply_filters( 'get_available_skins', $skins );
}
```

Then, users can create a custom plugin that sits alongside yours (activated separately so it won't interfere with your update) that does the following:

```
add_filter( 'get_available_skins', 'my_custom_skin' );
function my_custom_skin( $skins ) {
    $skins[] = '/my-custom-skin.css';

    return $skins;
}
```

This is the exact same way WordPress uses hooks to make itself extensible.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

<sub>*(Obviously, I don't know what plugin you're working with, what a custom skin looks like, or how you have things coded, so you'll have to use the code above merely as a model for how you can refactor your own code.)*</sub>